# Why this attached event listener is not executing?

Tags: javascript

This is my code :

```
var myinp = document.querySelector(".myinp");
var store = document.querySelector(".store");

myinp.addEventListener("input", function() {update(store);}, false);

function update(elem) {
  console.log('Executed');
  elem.style.left= this.value + "%";
  if(this.value>0) {
    elem.textContent= this.value;
  } else {
    elem.textContent= null;
  }
}
```

The console just shows one `Executed` and even then the `textContent` does not change.

**EDIT**

This version of code works:

```
myinp.addEventListener("input", update, false);

function update() {
  thumb.style.left= this.value + "%";
  if(this.value>0) {
    thumb.textContent= this.value;
  } else {
    thumb.textContent= null;
  }
}
```

When I am not passing any parameters why does `this` refer to the element and not window just like in first case?.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Check the scope under which your function is executing and see where 'this' is pointing to. You need to understand how Javascript scope works.

Comment: What kind of event `input` is? Input is an element, not an event

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude [this demo](http://codepen.io/abhisack/pen/WvLXdd) works with "input". Is there any explanation?

Comment: @CuriousMind - `this` and "scope" are different things.

Comment: Danggg... @nnnnnn you are right, its context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `update` function is executed in global context (`window`). If you want `this` to be an input instance you need to provide context explicitly:

```
myinp.addEventListener("input", function() {
  update.call(this, store);
}, false);
```

Remember that execution context depends on the *way* you invoke the function. In your case `update` is implicitly bound to the global object so calling it like `update()` will always have `this` being `window`.

Comment: Hello @dfsq, can you tell us what `input` event is?

Comment: @dfsq Your suggestion worked! Thanks :)
How does this work when I don't pass any parameter? I am updating the question to add another version of same function but without any parameters. I need to know to have a better understanding of JavaScript.

Comment: @dfsq I'd also link to something explaining how `this` works in detail, like:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: @SanJeetSingh If you don't want to pass parameters you could simple do `myinp.addEventListener("input", update, false);`

Comment: @dfsq When I am not passing any parameters why does `this` refer to the element and not window just like in first case?

Comment: @SanJeetSingh Because if the function used as event handler `this` is set to the HTMLElement event attached to. Take a look at the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler